# Is the Keeper of the Code (Jack Sparrow's father) immortal?

Tags: character, dialogue, pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

In *Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End*, during the scene where the Brethren Court meets to decide to fight against the East India Company (Lord Beckett), we hear this conversation between Jack and the *"Keeper of the Code"* (who is also his father)

> "What? You've seen it all, done it all. You survived. That’s the trick, isn’t it? To survive?"
>
> "It’s not just about living forever, Jackie. The trick is living with yourself forever."

Does it mean that he is immortal? There are some conversation also in next movie (*On Stranger Tides*), however I am not able to find conversation.

I am looking for reference if he is immortal or not. And if this conversation is not about immoratility then what is it about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jack's comment is about the fact that his father has lived to be an "Old Pirate" you will notice several times through the series that pirates don't generally live long enough to enjoy the fruits of their ill-gotten gains, which Captain Teague has done.

Captain Teague's comment is a bit more cryptic. He is revealing a crack in his swagger here. He admits that yes, he has survived a long time, but that the harder part is living with his past, not surviving it.

He advises against seeking immortality with his lifestyle, noting that his past will continue to haunt him forever, and the longer he lives, the more he will be haunted for.

While it doesn't confirm or deny his immortality, the exchange in *On Stranger Tides* is as follows:

> "I heard where you're headed. The Fountain."
> "Have you been there?"
> "Does this face looks like it's been to the Fountain of Youth?"
> "...Depends on the light."
> ―Edward Teague and Jack Sparrow